# Nginx return a file matched by four aliases

Tags: nginx, static-files

I am trying to serve a `react app` with `nginx`, and the browser downloads `build/index.html` which is accessed by aliases `/app/room/main`, `/app/room/create`, etc (it is necessary as the app's state depends on URL). How to serve this one file by many aliases without the browser downloading it.

Answer (score 0):

Serving react app with nginx.

```
    location /payments/room/ {
        # serve static files from build
        alias /path/to/build/;
    }

    location ~ ^/payments/room/(room-create-pick|settings|main|new-payment) {
        # these four links should be handled by my react app
        # (the index.html) should be returned
        alias /path/to/build/;
        try_files index.html =404;
    }
```